# ¿Por qué Android siempre me arroja Permiso denegado, aunque solicite permisos?

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, react-native

Necesito copiar un archivo SQLite de la memoria interna hacia las carpetas en dónde se instala mi aplicación.

Siempre obtengo el error:
`[Error: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/man/man.man: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)]`

Intente añadir a mis permisos `android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` pero cuando lo solicitaba decía que no se encontraba el Activity para solicitarlo

Acá lo que puse en mi archivo AndroidManifest.xml según lo que he investigado

```
<manifest ....>
    ..
    ..
    ..
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application ...
          android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
     >
        ..
        ..
        ..
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Solicitar permisos para Android desde React Native

```
    static async tienePermisoLecturaYEscritura() {
        try {
            if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
                const permisoLectura = await PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                const permisoEscritura = await PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                if (permisoLectura && permisoEscritura) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    const permisoSolicitado = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple(
                        [PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE],
                        {
                            title: "Permisos Mi Asistente de Negocios",
                            message: "La aplicación requiere permiso de leer y escribir en el almacenamiento del dispositivo.",
                            buttonNegative: "Negar permisos",
                            buttonPositive: "Conceder permisos"
                        }
                    );

                    if (permisoSolicitado == PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                    return false;
                }
        }
        catch (err) {
            if (__DEV__){
                console.log("Error en Utileria.tienePermisoLecturaYEscritura");
                console.log(err);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Función dónde quiero copiar un archivo de un lugar a otro, aclaró también que antes de copiar el archivo cierro los archivos SQLite antes de ponerme a trabajar en ellos, porque puedo borrar archivos en las carpetas de la instalación de la aplicación

```
static async RestaurarBaseDeDatos(){
        if(await Utileria.tienePermisoLecturaYEscritura()){
            try{
                const respuesta = await NativeModules.AArchivos.BuscarArchivo("*/*");

                if(respuesta === ""){
                    return {
                        cancelado: true,
                        exito: false
                    };
                }

                const bd_actual = Utileria.DirectorioArchivosManAplicacion + "/.././databases/man.man";
                const bd_nueva = respuesta;

                if(await Utileria.tienePermisoLecturaYEscritura()){
                    // Está linea si funciona, pero está en la carpeta dónde tengo instalada la aplicación
                    await fs.unlink(bd_actual);
                    // Está linea da el error Permission denied (react-native-fs)
                    await fs.copyFile(`${bd_nueva}`, `${bd_actual}`, { overwrite: true });

                    return {
                        cancelado: false,
                        exito: true
                    };
                }
                else{
                    throw "Permisos insuficientes para restaurar la base de datos.";
                }
            }
            catch(err){
                if(__DEV__){
                    console.log(err);
                }

                throw err;
            }
        }
        else{
            throw "Permisos insuficientes para abrir el archivo.";
        }
    }
```

Implementación de método nativo para control total de archivos y siempre arroja el error `Activity not found`.

```
package com.miasistentedenegocios.apermisos;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;

import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ActivityEventListener;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseActivityEventListener;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

public class APermisos extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    private Promise mPromesa;

    private int PERMISO_MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 10;

    // Constructor de la clase APermisos
    public APermisos(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    // Nombre que se utilizará en el lado de JavaScript para referirse a este módulo
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "APermisos";
    }

    private final ActivityEventListener activityListener = new BaseActivityEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if(resultCode != PERMISO_MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE){
                if(mPromesa != null){
                    mPromesa.resolve("");
                    mPromesa = null;
                }
                else{
                    mPromesa.reject("false", "Permiso cancelado.");
                    mPromesa = null;
                }
            }
            else
            if (resultCode == PERMISO_MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getReactApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        mPromesa.resolve(true);
                        mPromesa = null;
                    } else {
                        mPromesa.reject("false", "Permiso denegado.");
                        mPromesa = null;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    mPromesa.reject("false", "Permiso denegado por el sistema.");
                    mPromesa = null;
                }
            }
            else{
                mPromesa.reject("false", "Permiso cancelado.");
                mPromesa = null;
            }
        }
    };

    @ReactMethod
    public void SolicitarPermisoControlTotalArchivos(Promise promesa){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getReactApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                promesa.resolve(true);
                promesa = null;
            } else {
                Activity activityActual = getCurrentActivity();
                if(activityActual != null){
                    Intent intento = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", activityActual.getPackageName(), null);
                    intento.setData(uri);
                    activityActual.startActivityForResult(intento, PERMISO_MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
                else {
                    promesa.reject("false", "Error activity actual no disponible.");
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            promesa.reject("false", "Error, el permiso de MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE no está disponible para está versión.");
            promesa = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola veo que verificas que exista el permiso pero al no tenerlo deberia agregar la solicitud del permiso

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getReactApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        mPromesa.resolve(true);
                        mPromesa = null;
                    } else {
                        mPromesa.reject("false", "Permiso denegado.");
                        mPromesa = null;
                        "aqui debes agregar la solicitud"


requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, pasado un tiempo, ya logré pasar la cuestión del permiso, siempre obtengo permiso `GRANTED` de lectura y escritura, pero el permiso es revocado en el instante, arrojando el error `EACCES (Permission denied)]`.

Tengo duda también si existirá alguna herramienta para intentar rastrear de dónde podría venir el error, porque hice un proyecto nuevo desde cero, le implementa está lógica y funciona, lo paso a mi aplicación y ya no funciona, intente ver la memoria pero no logré nada.